# Problems when mocking HttpResponeBase and HttpRequestBase

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

I got a mvc 3 project where I want to mock HttpResonseBase and HttpRequestBase. Im using RhinoMocks 3.6 to mock myobjects. My test code rightnow looks like this.

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
    MockRepository repo = new MockRepositoy();
    HttpContextBase mockHttpContext= repo.StrictMock<HttpContextBase>();
    HttpRequestBase mockRequest = repo.StrictMock<HttpRequestBase>();
    HttpResponseBase mockResponse = repo.StrictMock<HttpResponseBase>();
    ICookie mockCookie = repo.StrictMock<ICookie>();
    Controller instanceToTest = new Controller(mockCookie);

    SetupResult.For(mockHttpContext.Request).Return(mockRequest);
    SetupResult.For(mockHttpContext.Response).Return(mockResponse);

    mocks.Replay(context);

    instanceToTest.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(mockHttpContext, new RouteData(), instanceToTest);

    mockCookie.Expect(x=>x.MethodToExpect("Test",mockRequest,mockResponse);


    mockRepository.ReplayAll();
    instanceToTest.MethodToTest();
    mockRepository.VerifyAll();
}
```

When im running the test I get this errormessage;

```
Rhino.Mocks.Exceptions.ExpectationViolationException: ICookie.MethodToExpect("Test", System.Web.HttpResponseBase, System.Web.HttpRequestBase); Expected #0, Actual #1.
ICookie.MethodToExpect("Test", HttpResponseBaseProxy); Expected #1, Actual #0.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that you use `StrictMock` - it means that if you call a method on the Mock object that you haven't set any expectations on it, `VerifyAllExpectations` will fail. You could use `MockRepository.GenerateMock<T>` method instead of the `StrictMock`.
Another comment is that you'd better stick with the [RhinoMocks AAA syntax](http://ayende.com/blog/3318/rhino-mocks-arrange-act-assert-syntax) (using the `Expect`, `Stub` and `VerifyAllExpectations` methods instead of `ReplayAll`, `SetupResult` etc...)
Here's how your code may look like with pure AAA syntax:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
    // Arrange(A) - create your objects, mocks and stubs
    // The context is a Stub - you just want it to return the mocked request and response
    HttpContextBase mockHttpContext= MockRepository.GenerateStub<HttpContextBase>();
    HttpRequestBase mockRequest = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpRequestBase>();
    HttpResponseBase mockResponse = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpResponseBase>();
    ICookie mockCookie = MockRepository.GenerateMock<ICookie>();
    Controller instanceToTest = new Controller(mockCookie);

    // Stub will return the mocked request and response on every call (similar to SetupResult)
    mockHttpContext.Stub(x => x.Request).Return(mockRequest);
    mockHttpContext.Stub(x => x.Response).Return(mockResponse);

    instanceToTest.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(mockHttpContext, new RouteData(), instanceToTest);

    mockCookie.Expect(x=>x.MethodToExpect("Test",mockRequest,mockResponse);

    // Act(A) - do the actual operations on the tested class
    instanceToTest.MethodToTest();

    // Assert (A) - Verify your expectations
    mockCookie.VerifyAllExpectations();
}
```